# Undefined config values in grails application

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-2.5

We are successfully using externalized configuration in grails to retrieve all needed values from a configuration file. Lately it "randomly" happens to us that values from the config are not defined in the application after restart. Although the config is parsed while the application boots (log entries).

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Our config file is containing about 5500 lines at the moment.

Comment: What version of Grails and what container are you running it in?

Comment: Hey, we use version 2.5.5 of Grails and deploy it as a WAR file in Tomcat.

Comment: How and where do you load the config properties stored in an external file?

Comment: @Tung We load it in Config.groovy with: 

`grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy","classpath:${appName}-config.groovy"]`

Comment: I've experienced the same issue (running grails 2.5.3) while running application in tomcat. Restarting tomcat makes the config entries "appear" again and restarting another time randomly makes the configuration entries dissapair (read as empty values [:]). Did you find any solution to this?